# Not able to click on link

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Here is the code
I want to click on 1st hospital "Abraham Lincoln Memorial Hospital".
Not able to click on 1st link on below image and exception thrown
1st entered "ab" in search box to search hospital name start with ab
then it open 2nd window to select the hospital, where is my code is not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqV6A.png)

```
 // Enter Hospital
            element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@placeholder,'Search Hospitals...')]"));
              element.SendKeys("ab");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver). ExecuteScript("argument[0].click();", element);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            Actions actions1 = new Actions(driver);
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//a[contains(@title,'Abraham Lincoln Memorial Hospital')]"))).Click();
            actions1.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@title,'Abraham Lincoln Memorial Hospital')]"))).Build().Perform();
            //actions1.Perform();
           // Actions actions2 = new Actions(driver);
           // actions2.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("//a[contains(@title,'Abraham Lincoln Memorial Hospital')]"))).Click();
            
           // element2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@title,'Abraham Lincoln Memorial Hospital')]"));
            //((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("argument[0].click();", element2);
            // element2.Click();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkUSA.png)

Comment: Please provide the link to the page you are working with. Picture is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The link to html would be helpful,
but you can try the following `xpath`:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Abraham Lincoln Memorial Hospital')]
```